# How to draw a text inside rectangle in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I want to draw a filled rect with a text inside using canvas.

This is my code:

```
Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(x,y,size,size,);
Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
canvas.drawRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(100.0)),paint,);
```

I don't know how to put a text inside a rect. Please help

Comment: I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use **TextPainter** class.
You can play around with the offset yourself

```
    TextPainter painter;
    painter = TextPainter(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    painter.text = TextSpan(
      text: 'Sample Text',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 40.0,
      ),
    );
    Offset position = Offset(
      x+2.0, 
      y+2.0,
    );
    painter.layout();
    painter.paint(canvas, position);
```